# Is there a way for EMMS to create playlists based on an existing directory structure?

Tags: emms

I (finally!) have a working EMMS to play my music collection, and would like to sort it into playlists. At the moment, my music directory (`~/Music/`) is already organized into folders (at the first level) which I would like to form the new playlists. Thus, I have an arrangement similar to this:

- The contents of `~/Music/foo` should form a playlist `foo`
- The contents of `~/Music/bar` should form a playlist `bar`
- etc.

Can this be done in EMMS, and if so, how? Ideally, I would like to do it programmatically, so that in future, if I add more music, it'll generate another playlist for me automatically.

Comment: I'm sure one could write a bit of elisp code to be triggered by `emms-playlist-mode-hook`, to check for relevant `.m3u` files in `~/Music/` and create new ones as needed. I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "form the new playlists"? If it is, you could probably do this more efficiently with a seperate script, outside of emacs.

Comment: Are you sure you need a playlist?  The emms browser has the capacity to sort by directory names.

Comment: Finally being the key point. Hellish to configure. I've given up again. Who designed this playlist mechanism? It's like wading through molasses.